# Freeswitch: how to recognize session is hanguped in lua script when executing with 'execute_on_answer'?

Tags: free, freeswitch

background:

I have such a command below to call some number, such as caller=12345, callee=54321 ,and when 54321 is answered, my_script.lua will be executed, thus to control session in my lua script .

But then when 54321 is hanguped by itself, in my lua script, session.ready() is always true, so it will be executed continued, this is not corrected.

```
originate {execute_on_answer='lua my_script.lua',hangup_after_bridge=true,origination_caller_id_number=12345}sofia/gateway/gw/54321 &echo
```

my question is :

how to recognize session is hanguped in lua script when callee hangup by itself ？ thks.

Answer (score 0):

I change the command and then it works.

```
originate {hangup_after_bridge=true,origination_caller_id_number=12345}sofia/gateway/gw/54321 &lua(robot/robot.lua 12345)
```

Comment: Sad. It works but it is executed no matter if callee is answered